# How to take the result from an action and pop up different messagebox?

Tags: python, shutil

I like to setup a GUI to copy/move files in windows.  If an action is completed, a messagebox pop up as done.  Otherwise, any error (ie. file/directroy not exist)will pop up a messagebox with an error.  Please help with any suggestion.  Thanks.

Tried with if statement
Tried with return statement

```
import tkinter as tk
import shutil, os
import tkinter.messagebox
def backup():
    shutil.copyfile(r'C:\Test\T\t1.txt', r'C:\Test\1\t1.txt')
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('title', 'done')
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror('title', 'error')
```

Comment: Why not use `try` and `except type-of-error` ?

Comment: It would help to show what you've tried. You can [edit] the question.